# Logarithmic equation with $\lg^2$

Tags: logarithms

$$\lg^210x+\lg x=19$$
Could anyone please help me to understand what exactly is squared in this equation? The whole logarithmic function? Some kind of example with numbers would be super helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the picture?

Comment: If $h$ is the function $h(t)=t^2$, then here $\operatorname{lg}^2$ definitely stands for $h\circ\operatorname{lg}$ and not for $\operatorname{lg}\circ\operatorname{lg}$. Now if it were me, I would contend that you could read $\operatorname{lg}^210x=(\operatorname{lg}10)^2x$, but jokes aside 99.9% of the time it's $(\operatorname{lg}(10x))^2$.

Comment: It can be both, $a(\log(10x))^2+\log(x)=19$ and $a\log(10x)^2+\log(x)=19$. In both cases (with the given value of $a=7.031$) there is solution to the equation.For the second case you have $x\approx0.4114$ and for the first case,more complicated, there are two solutions.

Comment: Good example ! Always put parentheses : otherwise what means $\sin a+b$ ? Same problem.

Comment: I concur with the others. It must be $(\lg(10x))^2$. We often use superscript like that for trigonometric functions: $\sin^2x$ is just $(\sin x)^2$ (and not, say, $\sin(\sin x)$), *and* this explanation also enables us to solve the problem as a quadratic equation in $\lg x$, in other words the problem looks nicer with *that* interpretation than with any other interpretation I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Just use that
$$\lg^2(10x) = (\lg(10x))^2 = (1+\lg x)^2 = 1 + 2\lg x +\lg^2x$$

So that your equation is a quadratic equation in $y=\lg x$.  To solve,
solve the quadratic equation in $y$ and then use $x=10^y$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I figured out the solution with quadratic, I just would like only to understand what exactly is squared. If we have e.g. log^2 based 2 of 8. What will be squared in that case? 3^2? The base will be squared, the argument or the whole function?

Comment: @Inna Khachikyan:  In most cases, $f^2(x)$ is short for $(f(x))^2$, i.e. first evaluate the function, and then square the result.  In your example $$\log_2^2(8) = (\log_2(8))^2 = 3^2$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a huge help